# Hiding my Google Cloud Endpoints API from the public

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

We have started a project few weeks ago using google cloud endpoints and other google cloud services (datastore, cloud sql etc...).

Our app will have the user go through a registration process where they will create their own username/password and provide other profile information. We don't want to authenticate using Google/Facebook/Twitter OAUTH. We also want to hide our API's from the public view.

Is there anyway possible for us to hide or not allow access to the API's from API explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Other than those provided, there are three possible security mechanisms:

1. [Specify Client IDs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/auth#Python_Specifying_authorized_clients_in_the_API_backend) at the API level, so that clients with that
   ID only can connect
2. Build your own OpenID provider that uses the
   user data from your store.
3. Login without endpoints before making endpoints call. Pass and validate the token inside your endpoints method.

Comment: However this will still not hide my other API's from the public view. I am planning to go with #3 solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your API is visible under API explorer I assume you have configuration similar to this:

```
@Api(clientIds = {
        ClockyEndpoint.WEB_CLIENT_ID,
        ClockyEndpoint.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
        Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID
})
```

Just remove the client ID `Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID` and it should no longer be accessible using API explorer.

Comment: This did not work for me. Tried this but am still able to view my app's API even from Incognito browser window.